# Why my MERN app yielded different results on a 32 bit pc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

well my code is too long to post bit i created a mongodb express node with React at front end , i built react and copied the file to the pc and served it with a express server, i copied the backend files and as well copied them to other pc i ran the server that hosts the react builded app , and the other express app , both in different ports of course , the if else statements yielded different results in the 32 bit computer , so did bcrypt a express dependency in authentication , has anyone had this problem?( Same node version on both)

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res ) => {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)

    const passhash = await bcrypt.hash(config.get('Rootpassword'), salt)
    const rootuser = {
        name: "Root",
        password: passhash ,
        isMaster: true,
      isRoot: true

    }
const rootpass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.Password, rootuser.password)

     if ( req.body.Username == rootuser.name && (rootpass)) {
           const token = await jwt.sign(rootuser, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))
           res.header('authtoken', token).send(rootuser.name)

        }

else  {
    let admin = await Admin.findOne({ name: req.body.Username})
    if (!admin) return res.status(403).send('Invalid username')
    console.log(admin)
    const validpass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.Password, admin.password)
    if(!validpass)  return res.status(403).send('Invalid password')
 const token = admin.generateToken();
 res.header('authtoken', token).send(_.pick(admin, ["name", "_id"]));
 console.log(token)


}

})
```

on the 32 bit version of node where i ran the local server bcrypt.compare always returns false even if req.body.password is = to rootuser.password and req.body.username==  req.body.Username. this is perfectly working in node.js on my local server please need help, also some data is coming incomplete in other forms in the 32 bit version

Comment: Can't really answer this question without seeing the statements that yielded different results on 32 vs 64 bit.

Comment: added the code  take a look at it man